# Index xml files from a outside website

Tags: python, xml, django

Using python django I would like to access this site http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/    It is a dictionary site for a language called esperanto,  I need to be able to search for a word, and get back its definition, it looks like Each Esperanto root word has an xml file,

1. I need to index each xml file
2. store the name of each xml file in a database.
3. On my website I need to $_GET the word.
4. I need to search for combinations of these root words with a xml file named after it.

Answer (score 2):

Most programming languages have access to both some sort of XML parser as well as some persistent embedded key-value store. Once you've decided on a programming language, just find one of each that you can feel comfortable with.

Comment: I am building a website out of php and javascript,  Where can I find information about these parsers for php

Comment: XML parsers: http://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.xml.php

Key-value stores: Too many. Start here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.database.php

Answer (score 2):

Wonder, if you have access to WSDL. You might be able to access the data that way.
What exactly is the problem you are encountering?

Answer (score 1):

As soon as you need indexing and fast search, it might worth looking for [XML database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_database) for storing your dictionary (especially for complex queries and big dictionaries). You can easily access most XML databases from PHP.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider such workflow for you:

1. Download all the files
2. Load their contents and filenames into database (any database will fit)
3. Setup sphinx search tool ( http://sphinx.pocoo.org/ )
4. Run sphinx to build an index for xml_contents
5. Design your application to use sphinx for search in index
6. Delete all file contains, leaving only filename and sphinx index in a database
7. When using sphinx search, you'll get a filename, operate with it as you supposed before

I'm not very familiar with sphinx and don't know is it capable to use files, to build it's index, that why I offer you to load all the information into database

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried asking the site's administrator for the data? Or perhaps he could set up a web service for you?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can fetch each XML file with `file_get_contents()`, curl, wget or the tool that pleases you the most.

Then, You can save the XML files on the file system, or even better use Oracle's Berkeley [DBXML](http://www.oracle.com/database/berkeley-db/xml/index.html), with it you can actually save the XML in the Database and query it, kinda like if it was SQL. It has PHP bindings and lets you query with XQuery. I used it to replace a XML web service and works like a charm, blazing fast.

For PHP XML parsing I used to use [Keith Devens' XML to Array](http://keithdevens.com/software/phpxml) parser, which is EASY, but it's now oldish Now I use CakePHP's own, you may want to use PHP's [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php). There are also JavaScript based parsers you could use on the client side of the app like [jParse](http://jparse.kylerush.net/) (jQuery).

This is the Page for PHP + dbXML but seems to be down: http://phpdbxml.4641.org/ but you can download it from here: http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/products/berkeley-db/index.html (there's the license too).

I hope it helps.